# Contact Form to output HTML email - Data not being entered in the email

Tags: php, html, email

I have been working on a contact form that would output to a html email that would be emailed to an address. The process works beautifully, but it is not putting the data inside the html email for the recipient to read.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  //create an empty errors array
  $errors = array();
  //our form has been submitted
  if($_POST['name'] == "") {
     //the name field is empty
     $errors[] = "The Name field is empty.";
  }
  if($_POST['business'] == "") {
     //the business field is empty
     $errors[] = "The Business name field is empty.";
  }
  if($_POST['telephone'] == "") {
     //the telephone number field is empty
     $errors[] = "The Telephone Number field is empty.";
  }
  if($_POST['email'] == "") {
     //the email field is empty
     $errors[] = "The Email address field is empty.";
  }
  if($_POST['enquiry'] == "") {
     //the enquiry field is empty
     $errors[] = "The Enquiry field is empty.";
  }
  if(!stripos($_POST['email'], '@')) {
      $errors[] = "The email address was not valid.";
  }
  if($_POST['antispam'] != 10) {
      $errors[] = "You entered the wrong numerical answer for the anti-spam question.";
  }
  if(count($errors) == 0) {

    // email settings
    $to  = 'email@address.com' . ', ';
    $subject = 'Website Enquiry Form';

    // headers
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Return-Path: email@address.com' . "\r\n";

    // form details
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $business = $_POST['business'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];
            $enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];

    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Website Enquiry Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>              
    The details from completed enquiry form on the website is: <br><br>   <strong> $name </strong>from <strong> $business </strong> has filled the form out. The contact details for<strong> $name </strong> is<strong> $telephone </strong> and<strong> $email </strong> is the listed email address.<br><br> <strong> $type </strong> is the selected type of enquiry.<br><br> <strong>Comments:</strong><br> $enquiry <br><br>This is the end of the enquiry form.
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

       if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
           $success = true;
       } else {
          $success = false;
       }
       } else {
          $success = false;
       }
    }
 ?>
```

This is the PHP for the Contact Enquiry Form. It is a modification of an existing one that I had previously, but without the HTML output, and the code in "message:" used to be:

```
<<<DATA
<strong>Name:</strong> $name <br>
<strong>Email:</strong> $email <br>
<strong>Why:</strong> $subject <br>
<strong>Comment:</strong> $comments<br>
DATA;
```

Which worked then, but I tried putting `<<<DATA` and ending with `DATA;` just before the HTML code, and it didn't work then. I am not really a developer so I would not know where to start. I hope someone could point me towards the right direction regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting your `$message` variable you are using single quotes (') to delimit the string. This causes php to *not* parse variables in the string. You can either use double quotes (") instead:

```
$message = "<html><body>Name: $name</body></html>";
```

Or concatenate strings like so:

```
$message = '<html><body>Name: '.$name.'</body></html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes on your $message variable like `$message = "<html>...</html>"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes in $message.